# Gradle wrapper ignores already installed distribution?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

The gradle wrapper distributions are located on my machine under:
C:\Users\Ruperto.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.10-all
In this folder I already had 2 folder with long names (78v82fsf226usgvgh7q2ptcvif, a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst) and now after running gradlew in the command line of Windows it downloaded the same version again and added a new folder to the above path, all of the 3 folders now have the same gradle version inside, same size also, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle Wrapper is downloaded from distribution URL.

**If you do not specify the distribution URL, default URL will be used**, e.g. https://services.gradle.org/distributions/.

**Gradle Wrapper binary is always downloaded once per distribution URL, even if it is exactly the same binary file** and it is stored in a directory that is basically hash of the distribution URL.