# gradlew (command line) and gradle from Android Studio will download duplicate tools

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

If you build an Android app using Android Studio's Run button, it will download the necessary gradle tool from the URL in `gradle-wrapper.properties` and build it. For example, Android Studio will download the 87 MB zip file: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip and unzip it to a location like:

> ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/123abc (271 MB folder)

But if you then rebuild the same app on the command line, using `./gradlew assembleDebug`, the **command-line gradle will re-download the same 87 MB zip file and unzip it to a new location** like:

> ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/456def **(duplicate 271 MB folder)**

This is slow and inefficient on disk space, as both folders contain exactly the same items. This also happens when using any gradle task on the command-line, like [`./gradlew --stop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21184794/how-to-stop-gradle-task-execution-in-android-studio).

- Why can't they both use the first downloaded tool?
- Is there a way to prevent this duplicate download?

Similar/related issues:

- [.gradle retains multiple copies of Gradle distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339270/gradle-retains-multiple-copies-of-gradle-distributions)
- [Why there are multiple copies for the same version of gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617070/why-there-are-multiple-copies-for-the-same-version-of-gradle)
- [Gradle wrapper ignores already installed distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543641/gradle-wrapper-ignores-already-installed-distribution)